Alternative way to gather insights from SHAP beeswarm/summary plot
everyone. I have been trying to find a way to use SHAP to explain my ML models. However, I find the interpretation of the beeswarm/summary plot a bit troublesome and ambiguous. The interpretation depends on the concentration, dispersion, and frequency of large or small values to infer the positive or negative impact of the feature. My direct question is:
Is there a way to gather this insight from another approach?
For instance, here is the beeswarm/summary plot for the Titanic dataset:

As you can see, larger values for the "sex" feature (1, representing male) result in lower chances of survival, and similarly, with "age," the younger the person, the better their chances of survival. However, I wouldn't be able to gather this information without looking at this particular plot, and even then, it can be somewhat ambiguous, as it's an image-based interpretation.
So, I decided to calculate the absolute SHAP values, and I got this:
    Feature  Mean_Absolute_SHAP_Value
1       Sex                  1.176998
0    Pclass                  0.875388
2       Age                  0.509288
3     SibSp                  0.311947
6  Embarked                  0.113004
5      Fare                  0.047917
4     Parch                  0.023691

I also gathered the SHAP mean values (not absolute), and got this:
    Feature  Mean_SHAP_Value
3     SibSp         0.091608
2       Age         0.041808
1       Sex         0.036215
4     Parch        -0.001433
5      Fare        -0.001719
6  Embarked        -0.001808
0    Pclass        -0.105661

Notice how the mean value indicates that "sex" is the most important feature. However, when we look at the mean SHAP values (without the absolute measure), the mean value for "sex" is very small. I thought that perhaps this approach would lead me in the right direction, but it didn’t. What would be the interpretation of this? Why is "sex" the most important feature, but its mean SHAP value (without the absolute measure) is so small?
I would be very grateful if you could please guide me on a more numerical approach to describe the positive or negative impact the values of my features have on my output. Specifically, I want to understand how different feature values affect my model—for example, the higher the square meters, the lower the likelihood of obtaining a lease, etc.
Thank you so much!

It's not a good idea to not use absolute values with SHAP as the values can be negative or positive and if you add them (like in computing the mean) you will probably get results not far from 0 as the + will more or less compensate for the -.
What is important is how far the SHAP coefficients are from 0 (either positive or negative), that's why we use absolute values to sum them.
You may be interrested in waterfall plots.
